# How to generate pdf using javascript libraries other than jspdf, html2pdf, pdfmaker, html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation

I've got an issue like image and text aren't quality while generate pdf using these libraries jspdf, html2pdf, pdfmaker, html2canvas. So, I want to know any other better Javascript library to generate pdf.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is a library recommendation request and, therefore, off topic on stack overflow...

Comment: Yes , This is library recommendation for pdf generation. I need sugggestion to use library which will be best to generate good quality  pdf. And this is not off topic too

Answer (score 0):

I have used [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) for generate pdf in one of my projects. It is good and easy to use. Haven't tried the images though. You may give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Dude!! But I have tried pdfmake js. Image is not Clear while using canvas

Comment: Dude I'm asking about javascript library to generate pdf.